# Storing hibernate sql result to arraylist

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I want to store the result into array list from this class. Currently, calling a PostgreSQL function named as `mis_personalregisterdetailreport().` This function result is directly mapped into this model class. Actually, i need to store the function result into an array list.  how can i do this?

```
package org.nic.eoffice.mis.efile.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery;
import org.nic.eoffice.mis.core.util.Util;

@Entity
@Immutable
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "PersonalRegisterModel", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = org.nic.eoffice.mis.efile.model.PersonalRegisterModel.class))
@NamedNativeQueries({

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findPersonalRegisterDetailReport", query = "{? = call mis_personalregisterdetailreport(:postdetailid, :fromDate, :toDate, :nature, :department, :office, :userName, :typeId, :sectionScope, :filterQuery, :orderQuery, :startIndex, :maxResults)}", resultSetMapping = "PersonalRegisterModel", callable = true) })
public class PersonalRegisterModel {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String receiptNumber;
    public String receiptDate;
    public String subject;
    public String sender;
    public String fileNumber;
    public String outsideNumber;
    public String submitOfficer;
    public String returnedToSection;
    public String form;
    public String draftDate;
    public String towhom;
    public String currentNo;
    public String countReceipt;

    public String file_id;
public ArrayList<PersonalRegisterListModel>  list=new ArrayList<PersonalRegisterListModel>();


    public String getFile_id() {
        return file_id;
    }

    public void setFile_id(String file_id) {
        this.file_id = file_id;
    }

    public String getCountReceipt() {
        return countReceipt;
    }

    public void setCountReceipt(String countReceipt) {
        this.countReceipt = countReceipt;
    }

    public String getCurrentNo() {
        return currentNo;
    }

    public void setCurrentNo(String currentNo) {
        this.currentNo = currentNo;
    }

    public String getTowhom() {
        return towhom;
    }

    public void setTowhom(String towhom) {
        this.towhom = towhom;
    }

    public String getDraftDate() {
        return draftDate;
    }

    public void setDraftDate(String draftDate) {
        this.draftDate = draftDate;
    }

    public String getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(String form) {
        this.form = form;
    }
public String getReturnedToSection() {
        return returnedToSection;
    }

    public void setReturnedToSection(String returnedToSection) {
        this.returnedToSection = returnedToSection;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getOutsideNumber() {
        return outsideNumber;
    }

    public void setOutsideNumber(String outsideNumber) {
        this.outsideNumber = outsideNumber;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getReceiptNumber() {
        return receiptNumber;
    }

    public void setReceiptNumber(String receiptNumber) {
        this.receiptNumber =receiptNumber;
    }

    public String getReceiptDate() {
        return receiptDate;
    }

    public void setReceiptDate(String receiptDate) {
        this.receiptDate = receiptDate;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getSubmitOfficer() {
        return submitOfficer;
    }

    public void setSubmitOfficer(String submitOfficer) {
        this.submitOfficer = submitOfficer;
    }


    public String getFileNumber() {
        return fileNumber;
    }

    public void setFileNumber(String fileNumber) {
        this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want mapping the result to list, not need to be like this;

**`createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(***.class).list();`**

Comment: your code only hibernate java Model,if you want query result ,you can create a service class call hibernate api.

Comment: please give an example